# .htaccess: GET variables are lost in rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Apparently, my .htaccess rewrite eats up all `$_GET`-variables on my page:

When accessing the URL http://192.168.1.1/welcome/test?getvar=true and running `var_dump($_GET)` in my index.php file, I get this this output:

```
array
'/welcome/test' => string '' (length=0)
```

So no `$_GET`-data available and no sign of the `getvar`-variable from my URL.

Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What should I change to ensure that my rewrite is working as intended but `$_GET`-variables still are accessible?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need the "QueryString Append" option:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=/$1 [QSA,L]`

Edit: Added @DonSeba's contribution, because it is correct.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working well. A quickie: It appears that the ending slash is required for `$_GET` params to be caught. Would it be possible to have the cake and eat it, ie. be able to do both `welcome/test?avar=1` & `welcome/test/?avar=1`? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure on that one.  Could it be your missing variable name?

Comment: Tested and works fine without the enging slash here.
Used it for JQuery UI Autocomplete, because that always appends the `term` parameter. `RewriteRule ^service/autocomplete/(.+)$ autocomplete.php?type=$2 [QSA,L]`.

Comment: never saw that you refered to me in your answer, thank you :)

Comment: Note the fact that there cannot be a space between the QSA,L. [QSA,L]

Comment: wish i knew this before using php to parse the url and reset the get variables manually!

Answer (score 10):

minor detail change :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now all routes will be visible in $_GET["route"]

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$ index.php?/$1&$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^myapi(.*) ./my_real_api_file.php? [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Did the trick for me.

You can now request: http://www.mydomain.com/myapi?foo=xy&bar=ab

and will be redirected to: http://www.mydomain.com/my_real_api_file.php?foo=xy&bar=ab

Can be quite usefull to hide your api code.