# .htaccess redirect losing GET variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the htaccess I have setup for my MVC.

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On  
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
    </IfModule>
```

So any request to *localhost/users/* will redirect to *localhost?url=users/*

But when there are some get data available in the url for example: *localhost/users/?msg=hello*

I'm missing the *?msg=hello* in the $_GET['url']. Is it possible to redirect to something like *localhost/users/msg=hello/*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `"QueryString Append"` option,

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Referred from :[.htaccess: GET variables are lost in rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6656413/htaccess-get-variables-are-lost-in-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do would be pretty complicated. As an alternative you could try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

When using that Rule you can access the URL via $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

The Reason you're loosing the get parameters is because the server creates the URL with two '?'. Ex:

```
http://localhost/?url=users/?msg=123
```